# How to show modal in cocos2d game application?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, modalviewcontroller

I want to know how to show modal view in cocos2d? Any one can help me?

Thanks before. Regards. :)

Answer (score 1):

I use this code for presenting a GKLeaderboard within cocos2d.

```
    GKLeaderboardViewController *leaderboardController = [[GKLeaderboardViewController alloc] init];

    UIViewController *container = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    [container setView:[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView]]; 
    [container setModalTransitionStyle: UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical];

    leaderboardController.leaderboardDelegate = container;

    [container presentModalViewController: leaderboardController animated: YES];
```

This will do what you want. Don't forget you need to release the UI objects when your done with them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Bongeh but it's not show like a normal modal view. I can't see all modal view and the modal move from right to left not from bottom to top.

Comment: My game use all orientation. Both landscape and potrait.

Comment: You need to alter this [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation, to let the modal view controller know the orientation, i am not 100% sure, I've never tried this in landscape

Comment: dude ur answer has nothing to do with the question :(

Comment: sure it does, create a UIViewController, set the view to the openGLView, give it a modal transition style, tell the uiviewcontroller to present another view controller modally (in this case GKLeaderboardViewController).